# traffic manager nested profiles and the front door

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-traffic-manager

i want to do a nested traffic manager solution in azure which then connects to front door.

i have a domain api.example.com and i want this to be the top level of traffic manager.

it should load balance between eu-api.example.com and us-api.example.com and then the nested traffic manager should balance each - the first one between eu1-api.example.com and eu2-api.example.com, and the second one between us1-api.example.com and us2-api.example.com.

these should then be endpoints in the front door. is this possible? and how to do it?

there seems to be an issue where both api.example.com and eu-api.example.com has to be configured as a CNAME for the host name of Traffic Manager and as a custom domain on Front Door so we cannot have this universal endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It is not best practice to combine Azure Traffic Manager with Azure Front Door. Please see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/best-practices)

Have you considered doing something along the lines of using Azure Front Door with Rule Sets to manage the traffic to the correct Origin Group, one for EU and one for US. The Origin Groups then can point to Internal Load Balancers which in turn can manage the connection to the final endpoint.

[image: Possible Design]

You can do Georouting via the rulesets in Azure Front Door.

[image: georuleset]

Comment: i dont think there is a traffic manager georouting equivalent in front door, or is there?

Comment: You can do it with  geo rules. I have updated the answer.